# How can I show transformation from uniform distribution to exponential distribution in R?

Tags: r, statistics, transformation, uniform, exponential-distribution

When variable `X` has uniform distribution (0,1), I can make a formula `Y = -(lambda)lnX` and the distribution of `Y` would show `Exp(lambda)`.

And I'm trying to prove this case when `lambda` is 3, showing that two distribution curves match.
I've made it this far, but can't figure out really how.

```
w <- seq(0, 10, length=500)
x <- dunif(w, 0, 1)
y <- (-1)*(3)*log(x)
z <- dexp(w, 3)
plot(w, y, type="l")
par(new=F)
plot(w, z)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem related to inverse CDF method.

First of all, you get inverse CDF wrong. It is `-1/3`, not `-3`.

Secondly, as the name suggests, it is inverse CDF, not inverse PDF. You can't do such transformation on density function. Instead, draw samples and use quantile-quantile plot.

```
n <- 500
x <- runif(n)
y <- -1/3 * log(x)
z <- rexp(n, 3)
qqplot(y, z)
abline(0, 1)
```

Alternatively, compare empirical CDF with theoretical CDF.

```
plot(ecdf(y))
curve(pexp(x, 3), add = TRUE, col = 2)
```